# AngularJS - Directive + ng-repeat, 5 elements, loops 15 times

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to add dynamically pictures to my divs, which i get over the [url2img](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Take-A-Snapshot-of-A-Webpage-url2img/) plugin. which works fine. But when I am looping via a ng-repeat, it loads the last picture for every div in my loop. so it is looping 15 times. I had 2 approaches are not working right now.

1.) HTML + load-img-from-ext<-directive

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div>
        {{link.title}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-thumb-ext" id="thumb-{{$index}}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" load-img-from-ext="{{link.url}}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

1.) Directive

```
.directive("loadImgFromExt", ['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
      link: timer(function (scope, elem, attr) {

          $(".img-thumb-ext").each(function () {
             console.log(attr[loadImgFromExt]);
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + attr["loadImgFromExt"] + '&screenshot=true',
              context: this,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
                $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
              }
            });
          })
        }
      }
    }
 }])
```

Which loops 15 times for 5 elements thats being rendered on screen.
So the output of the console log is

> 0
>
> 0 1
>
> 0 1 2
>
> 0 1 2 3
>
> 0 1 2 3 4

And my src for the images are overwritten by the last image.

2.) Second Approach
HTML + emit-last-repeater-element<-directive
+data-url in img

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links" emit-last-repeater-element>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div>
        {{link.title}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-thumb-ext" id="thumb-{{$index}}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" alt="{{link.url}}" data-url="{{link.url}}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

2.) Directive

```
.directive('emitLastRepeaterElement', function() {
    return function(scope) {
      if (scope.$last){
        scope.$emit('LastRepeaterElement');
      }
    };
  });
```

2.) Controller that calls

```
$scope.$on('LastRepeaterElement', function(){
      console.log('good to go');
      $('img[data-url]').each(function() {
        console.log($(this)[0].attributes[3])
        console.log($(this)[0].attributes[3].nodeValue);
        //var myUrl = $(this)[0].attributes[3];
        console.log($(this).data('url'));
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + $(this).data('url') + '&screenshot=true',
          context: this,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
            $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

This works, so that it loops only 5 times. but `$(this).data('url');` outputs `{{link.url}}`, instead of an url like `http://www.google.com`.

`$(this)[0].attributes[3]` outputs `data-url="http://www.google.com"` and is a type of `object`

`$(this)[0].attributes[3].nodeValue ouputs {{link.url}}` and is a type of `string`

Can anyone tell me how i can loop through this only 5 times and get the urls in the right format?

So the `{{link.url}}` should be e.g. http://www.google.com or http://www.yahoo.com so that i can use it inside of the `url` property in my ajax request.

Comment: Every time your link function runs, you're using jQuery to iterate over every existing DOM node with a matching class; that means every iteration is acting on all the previous iterations.  Stop using jQuery methods in Angular. Have each directive act on its own contents only.    

Angular and jQuery: two great tastes that taste *terrible* together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming to believe that jQuery expertise is an active hindrance to learning Angular: many of the  techniques you're used to are the exact opposite of what you should do in Angular. You're clearly in the habit of using the DOM as a data store -- in Angular you need to think of it more as a side-effect representation of the data model.

Each directive already has its own `link.url` on scope, so there is no need to crawl through the DOM in jQuery gathering up every `link.url` from every other directive. Similarly there's no reason to keep reading and setting data on DOM attributes -- use the directive scope; all the data you need is already there.

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div>{{link.title}}</div>
      <div>
        <img ng-src="{{link.parsedUrl}}">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and in the directive link function, construct `link.parsedUrl` directly from `link.url`:

```
$.ajax({ // or, better, use $http
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + scope.link.url + '&screenshot=true',
    context: this,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
        scope.link.parsedUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, I am pretty new to angular... I tried that in that way, and it works perfectly.  but I made slightly changes to it. It wont work with `scope.link.parsedUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;` instead I wrote `elem.attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);` and this works, can you explain why?

Comment: Not sure what went wrong for you there. Here's a toy sample of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/on8kcL1m/2/    (This would be one of the few cases where setting the attribute directly as you did would be safe -- inside a directive, modifying only its own internal DOM -- but it's still a jQuery habit worth unlearning. Angular doesn't know about any changes you make directly to the DOM and tends to overwrite them with what it thinks is the current state.)